# Selecting ID + any number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-selectors

I'm new to stackoverflow and jQuery altogether, so I'm having a little trouble making a simple function.

I basically have in my website a random number of links with `id "filtro" + "some number"`, and I want to write only one code to the action of clicking in any of them (that would later impact on the class with same "filtro" + "some number").

**Eg.: Click "#filtro3", do something on ".filtro3".**

The problem is, I don't know how to write the string in jQuery for "any number". I'm thinking about doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#" + "filtro" + SOME NUMBER).click(function () {
            //Do something with the element "." + "filtro" + SOME NUMBER
    });
});
```

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Ps.: This is my first question, and I apologize if I made any mistakes.

---

SOLVED. dystroy's solution worked like a charm.

For future reference to others, I was making this code to make a simple **filter menu for a picture gallery**. This way I could hide/show pictures of certain topics.

Comment: Use the "attribute starts with" selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `data-*` instead of IDs for selecting your elements. For example, `<a data-filtro=6 href='...'>link</a>`. Then you can select using `$('[data-filtro]')` and use `$(this).data('filtro')` inside the callback. IMO it's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to want

```
$(function () {
    $("[id^=filtro]").click(function () {
        var num = this.id.slice(6);
        // if there is a risk of ambiguity, you might check here that +num==num
        var $elem = $('.filtro'+num);
        ...
    });
});
```

Explanations :

- `$("[id^=filtro]")` uses the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements whose id starts with "filtro"
- `this.id.slice(6);` takes the part of the id starting after the sixth character. Maybe it would be clearer as `this.id.slice('filtro'.length)` or `this.id.substring('filtro'.length)`

Comment: `I'm new to stackoverflow and jQuery altogether` - a little explanation might help

Comment: @Ian You're right some parts might be hard to get. I've edited. Do you think something is missing ?

Comment: Hmm no, I think that's good :) It might be "better" to extract the number with a regex, but I think your example/explanation is good for how you're handling that

Comment: Thanks, the code and explanations were perfect. Worked like a charm. It was also way simpler than I expected. I'll edit the original post too for reference to others.

Answer (score 3):

There are some good answers to your original question, but I would like to suggest a potentially cleaner alternative.

You could use `data-*` attributes instead of IDs for selecting your elements. For example, your elements could look like

```
<a data-filtro=6 href='...'>link</a>
<a data-filtro=7 href='...'>link</a>
<a data-filtro=8 href='...'>link</a>
```

Then you can select these elements using `$('[data-filtro]')` and use `$(this).data('filtro')` inside the callback. For example,

```
$("[data-filtro]").click(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  var num = ele.data('filtro');
  // do whatever you want with num
});
```

This technique is used in many places, including the Foundation framework. It makes it easier to extract your behavior into a separate plugin that isn't dependent on element IDs. As the application becomes more complicated and the number of behaviors tied to each element grows, each element will look like

```
<a data-filtro=6 data-foo data-bar href="...">link</a>
```

instead of

```
<a id="filtro-6_and_bar_and_foo" href="...">link</a>
```

Comment: This is a great point! This is definitely the way to organize this :)

Answer (score 2):

If the `id` of the clicked element and the `class` of the elements that you want to change are the same, then it should be as simple as using the `id` of the element as the input for the class selector:

Using your code as a base:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id^=filtro]").click(function () {
        $("." + $(this).prop("id")).some_method_here();
    });
});
```

For example, I'm assuming that the target elements are `<div>`s . . . this would cause any `<div>` elements with the matching class to display in red text:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id^=filtro]").click(function () {
        $("div",  "#filterTest").css("color", "#000000");
        $("." + $(this).prop("id")).css("color", "#FF0000");
    });
});
```

Since I see you're new to JQuery . . .

- As dystroy said, `$("[id^=filtro]")` selects all elements that have and `id` that begin with "filtro".
- `$(this).prop("id")` gets the `id` of the current element (i.e., the one that has just been clicked)
- `$("." + $(this).prop("id"))` takes that `id` and makes it part of a class selector, by adding the "." to the beginning.  This will select all elements that have a `class` value that is the same as the `id` value of the element that you clicked.

**Edit:** - you could also use `this.id` (standard JavaScript) in place of `$(this).prop("id")`, which is simply JQuery's way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Know your JS. Instead of `$(this).prop("id")` use `this.id`

Comment: I know my JS . . . I used JQuery instead, since I was already using JQuery.

Comment: He stated in the comments to dydstroy's answer that `I'm new to stackoverflow and jQuery altogether` . . . he seems to want to know more about JQuery, so I'm helping him learn JQuery.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I added a comment explaining the options.

Comment: My first comment was more for the OP than for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id^=filtro]").click(function() {
     $('.someClassName'+ this.id.match(/\d+/) ).toggle();      
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ixiwuq/2/edit)**

The `^` in `[id^=filtro]` is the *"Starts With"* selector which will `match` any element  
which ID *starts with* `filtro`

**Now let's use a bit of Regex to retrieve the number out of the ID,**
`this.id.match(/\d+/);` gets the "this clicked element ID" name and retrieves all numbers `d+`
 That number is than used to match your CLASS element selector.